# How to I transfer an Image to an array of UIImage from another class?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, class

So I have an image that I can create from the camera and I want to transport it to another class with a type UIImage that already have a couple of things in it. The array is connected to a UICollectionView.

I have no idea how to do it I am still knew to swift and programming in general but I just love learning. If anyone has any suggestions that would me much appreciated.

This is the function of the collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoverCollectionViewCell

        cell.titleLable.text = Stuff[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.image = stuffImages[indexPath.item]
        return cell

    }
```

and below is the array that I have created

```
let stuffImages : [UIImage] = [

        UIImage(named: "1")!,
        UIImage(named: "2")!,
        UIImage(named: "3")!,]
```

This is in the other class with my futile attempt

```
 var discover = MainViewController()
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        imageCam.image = image

        discover.stuffImages[]

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I am just lost and would really appreciate your help thanks

Comment: How both classes are related?

Comment: with --> var discover = MainViewController()

Comment: the other class is called CamViewController

Comment: are you looking to append a image to your existing array

Comment: yes from another class

Comment: from a function in another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change stuffImages array to static variable

```
static var stuffImages : [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "1")!,
        UIImage(named: "2")!,
        UIImage(named: "3")!,]
```

And when you want to add a new image append to this array

```
MainViewController.stuffImages.append(image)
```

In MainViewController reload collection view

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thanks I have tried doing that but it doesn't appear on the collectionView. Should I add something in the collectionView?

Comment: @Nael In MainViewController's viewWillAppear reload collectionview

Comment: you mean in override func viewDidLoad()? How do I do that if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //your code
        }

Comment: It still didn't work the collectionView doesn't change :(

Comment: could it be because of my array with a string that is passed thought the collectionView

Answer (score 0):

I would like to appreciate your work.

**This is the function of the collectionView**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tapped \(indexPath.item)")
    var val = array[indexPath.item] //val is the which is going to give you the exact one
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle :nil)
    let newVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier : "image") as! ViewControllerImage
    newVC.array.append(value) //Line used to append a value
    self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**This is in the other class**

Here I Have created a array of string in your case it is UIImage that is the only difference

```
import UIKit
class ViewControllerImage: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var imgz: UIImageView!

var array : [String] = [
"hello"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("value appended \(array)")       
}
```

I hope it is useful...Once again I would like to appreciate your effort on learning